# copy and rename by specific condition - batch

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, rename

I would like to recursively [copy](/questions/tagged/copy) and [rename](/questions/tagged/rename) all files within a directory.

I have file pattern like `AAAJ_J1DO.docx`, but I want to change it to `AAAJ.docx` by creating the folder name `AAAJ`

Condition to find the name before underscore and create folder in that naming copy within renamed file.

For file patterns examples below:

> `D:\yogib\AAAJ_J1DO.docx` **->** `D:\yogib\AAAJ\AAAJ.docx`
> `D:\yogib\JACCC_loca.docx` **->** `D:\yogib\JACCC\JACCC.docx`
> `D:\yogib\KUJO1_ju2.docx` **->** `D:\yogib\KUJO1\KUJO1.docx`

I tried

```
 xcopy /s/y d:/yogib/*_*.docx d:/yogib/*/*.docx
```

Comment: Hi compo, question is simple i want to change the file name "AAAJ_J1DO.docx" as " AAAJ.docx" by excluding the text after underscore and create a folder in that name "AAAJ" (before underscore) and paste renamed within it. Hope it is clear now

Comment: Like so `AAAJ_J1DO.docx -> AAAJ\AAAJ.docx`?

Comment: folder should be in renamed file name

Comment: @Yogib the sentence does not make any sense. Please provide a full example including the folder structure before and afterwards.

Comment: Provided full example of folder structure

Comment: @Yogib Adapted my solution. Should work as intended.

Comment: @Yogib, Windows uses back slashes as directory separators! Whilst the command interprter is capable of understanding Unix path separators, _forward slashes_, you should not use them.

Comment: thank u very much urbansoft this is what i have been searching for a month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Edit: Reflect question changes.
2. Edit: Removed unnecessary code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%A IN (*.docx) DO (
    SET name=%%A
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%B in ("!name!") do set prefix=%%B
    IF NOT EXIST "!prefix!" MKDIR "!prefix!"
    MOVE "!name!" "!prefix!\!prefix!.docx"
)
```